# How would I pipe with a timeout that resets with each incoming?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, haskell-pipes

The `withTimeout` function is suppose to pipe `ConsoleEvent` with a `CeTimeout` sent every `s :: Int` seconds if nothing has been received. Instead it fails to send the `CeTimeout` events at the appropriate times.  One `CeTimeout` event is replaced for other events if greater than `s` seconds have passed with the original event being lost. Also instead of one `CeTimeout` event, it should be `n*s` `CeTimeout` events with `n` counting for each `s` second period that has passed.  Where is the mistake, and what would be the correction?  Thanks!

```
withTimeout :: (MonadIO t) => Int -> Pipe ConsoleEvent ConsoleEvent t ()
withTimeout ((* 1000000) -> s) = join . liftIO $ work
  where
    work :: (MonadIO t) => IO (Pipe ConsoleEvent ConsoleEvent t ()) 
    work =
      do
        (oSent, iKept) <- spawn $ bounded 1
        (oKept, iSent) <- spawn $ unbounded
        (oTimeout, iTimeout) <- spawn $ bounded 1

        tid <- launchTimeout oTimeout >>= newMVar

        forkIO $ do
          runEffect . forever $ fromInput iKept >-> factorTimeout tid oTimeout >-> toOutput oKept

        forkIO $ do
          runEffect . forever $ fromInput iTimeout >-> toOutput oKept

        return $ do
          await >>= (liftIO . guardedSend oSent)
          (liftIO . guardedRecv $ iSent) >>= yield

    guardedSend :: Output ConsoleEvent -> ConsoleEvent -> IO ()
    guardedSend o ce =
      (atomically $ send o ce) >>= \case
        True -> return ()
        otherwise -> die $ "withTimeout can not send"

    guardedRecv :: Input ConsoleEvent -> IO ConsoleEvent
    guardedRecv i =
      (atomically $ recv i) >>= \case
        Just a -> return a
        otherwise -> die $ "withTimeout can not recv"

    launchTimeout :: Output ConsoleEvent -> IO ThreadId
    launchTimeout o =
      forkIO . forever $ do
        threadDelay $ s
        (atomically $ send o CeTimeout) >>= \case
          True -> return ()
          otherwise -> die "withTimeout can not send timeout"

    relaunchTimeout :: Output ConsoleEvent -> ThreadId -> IO ThreadId
    relaunchTimeout o oldTid = 
      do
        tid <- launchTimeout o
        killThread oldTid
        return tid

    factorTimeout :: MVar ThreadId -> Output ConsoleEvent -> Pipe ConsoleEvent ConsoleEvent IO ()
    factorTimeout v o =
      do
        ce <- await
        liftIO . modifyMVar_ v $ relaunchTimeout o
        yield ce
```

Here is a fully executable [script](https://gist.github.com/binq/360a545cdf9b5b514f1ce420531070a6).

Comment: Slightly offtopic: it would be nice if you would provide a fully executable code as a script which includes imports [as shown here](https://haskell-scripting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/simple_scripts.html). Thank you!

Comment: @KostiantynRybnikov the fully executable code is at this link: https://gist.github.com/binq/360a545cdf9b5b514f1ce420531070a6

Comment: Is there a reason why you repeatedly spawn new `(i, o)` inside `withTimeout` instead of sending timeouts to the `i` generated in `main`?

Comment: You call `launchTimeout` again just after killing the timeout thread, but the only consumer is `ceRecv`, which is only going to remove the event that `factorTimeout` just sent. When the second timeout thread tries to send the timeout, the other end may have been GCed, so the output is sealed and you get the error.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, I corrected my code to fix the problems that you pointed out.  The function still does not work, but it fails in a different way.  Please see my updated post.  Thanks!

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I'm repeatedly spawn new (i, o) inside withTimeout because I want it to be entirely self contained.  Is not that possible?

Comment: What should be self contained? This indirection seems a superfluous source of complexity waiting for a bug to happen. Is it actually a minimized excerpt of an application where that architecture is required? And why does the updated code still call launchTimeout twice in an iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a `Pipe` will only allow one `yield` per `await`.  This means that a `CeTimeout` can not arbitrarily be sent down the pipe because nothing came into the pipe to cause the flow.  I will have to go through the source to confirm this; in the meantime this function has been refactored to return a `Pipe` and a `Producer` instead of just a `Pipe`.  The `Producer` can then be joined back in the calling function. The initial plan was to return just a `Pipe` so that the calling function would not have to do any additional work to make timeouts work.  That would have been a more self contained solution.  This alternative is nice in that it is more explicit.  The timeouts won't look like they are appearing out of thin air to someone that is not familiar with the pipeline.

```
withTimeout :: (MonadIO t) => Int -> IO (Pipe ConsoleEvent ConsoleEvent t (), Producer ConsoleEvent t ())
withTimeout ((* 1000000) -> s) =
  do
    (oTimeout, iTimeout) <- spawn $ bounded 1
    vTid <- launchTimeout oTimeout >>= newMVar

    return (factorTimeout vTid oTimeout, fromInput iTimeout)
  where
    launchTimeout :: Output ConsoleEvent -> IO ThreadId
    launchTimeout o =
      forkIO . forever $ do
        threadDelay $ s
        (atomically $ send o CeTimeout) >>= \case
          True -> return ()
          otherwise -> die "withTimeout can not send timeout"

    relaunchTimeout :: Output ConsoleEvent -> ThreadId -> IO ThreadId
    relaunchTimeout o oldTid = 
      do
        tid <- launchTimeout o
        killThread oldTid
        return tid

    factorTimeout :: (MonadIO t) => MVar ThreadId -> Output ConsoleEvent -> Pipe ConsoleEvent ConsoleEvent t ()
    factorTimeout v o =
      do
        ce <- await
        liftIO . modifyMVar_ v $ relaunchTimeout o
        yield ce

main :: IO ()
main =
  do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    hSetEcho stdin False

    exitSemaphore <- newEmptyMVar
    (o1, i1) <- spawn $ bounded 1
    (o2, i2) <- spawn $ bounded 1

    (timeoutTrap, timeoutRender) <- withTimeout 2

    runEffect $ yield CeBegan >-> toOutput o1

    forkIO $ do
      runEffect . forever $ chars >-> toOutput o1
      putMVar exitSemaphore ()

    -- other inputs would be piped to o1 here

    forkIO $ do
      runEffect . forever $ fromInput i1 >-> timeoutTrap >-> toOutput o2
      putMVar exitSemaphore ()

    forkIO $ do
      runEffect . forever $ timeoutRender >-> toOutput o2
      putMVar exitSemaphore ()

    forkIO $ do
      -- logic would be done before dumpPipe
      runEffect . forever $ fromInput i2 >-> dumpPipe >-> (await >> return ())
      putMVar exitSemaphore ()

    takeMVar exitSemaphore
```

Here is a fully executable [script](https://gist.github.com/binq/360a545cdf9b5b514f1ce420531070a6).