# Await with timeout using purescript-pipes

Tags: purescript, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to use a combination of [purescript-pipes](https://github.com/felixSchl/purescript-pipes/tree/v8.0.0), and [purescript-pipes-aff](https://github.com/felixschl/purescript-pipes-aff) to write a version of [`await`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-pipes/8.0.0/docs/Pipes#v:await) which will return `Nothing` if it doesn't receive a value in a specified amount of time.

So far, I've written the following:

```hs
timeOut :: forall a b. Milliseconds -> Pipe a b Aff (Maybe a)
timeOut t = do
  av <- liftAff  AVar.empty
  chan <- liftAff (spawn $ new)
  liftEffect $ launchAff_  do
      vv <- map join $ sequential $ oneOf
              [ parallel $ Nothing <$ (delay t)
              , parallel $ (Just <$> recv chan)
              ]
      AVar.put vv av
      seal chan
  P.take 1 >-> toOutput chan
  liftAff $ AVar.read av
```

This nearly works, however when it times out, it still waits for the next input, and consumes it, before returning. This makes sense based on the definition of `toOutput`, [which involves calling `await`](https://github.com/felixSchl/purescript-pipes-aff/blob/master/src/Pipes/Aff.purs#L183).

---

I'm not 100% sure that it's possible to write such a function, using the pipes streaming model, but I'd love to have this confirmed (or disproved)

Comment: You might want to translate this into Haskell and ask the question that way. It looks like I'm almost the only person here answering PureScript questions, and I have absolutely no familiarity with that library. I will get around to looking at it eventually, but it will probably take quite a while.

Comment: I'm wary that'd wind out fairly similar to (although subtly distinct from) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540672/how-would-i-pipe-with-a-timeout-that-resets-with-each-incoming); so I'll probably try and adapt the aproach in that rather than asking a new question